# Logstash.service not-found by systemctl

Tags: service, logstash, centos7, systemctl

I'm trying to set ElasticStack but I had problems with Kibana and Logstash, I could solve Kibanas issue, but after some days, my CentOS 7 machine don't recognise logstash.service.

I think that this is not a logstash issue, instead is a CentOS7 or a Systemd issue.

How do you think I can make my logstash.service appear again?

I had erase and reinstall logstash many times.

This is my "systemctl -a":

● logstash.service                                                                         not-found inactive dead      logstash.service

Comment: Is the service file exist in `/etc/systemd/system` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: May you can do `sudo yum -d10 reinstall logstash` for more verbose informations.

Comment: This is what displays, but service is still not-found:
Running transaction
  Installing    : 1:logstash-7.0.0-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                               1/1
could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH
  Checking   : 1:logstash-7.0.0-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                               1/1

Comment: VerifyTransaction time: 0.320
Transaction time: 18.380
installed:
  logstash.noarch 1:7.0.0-1

Comment: May you need to resolv java problem before install.

Comment: I execute:

#sudo yum install java-openjdk-devel java-openjdk

And then:

#sudo yum -d10 reinstall logstash

After reboot, it seems to be solve, but:

#systemctl status logstash

Unit logstash.service could not be found.

Comment: Strange but may you have a SysV file in `/etc/init.d/logstash` ?

Comment: This directory does not exist in my machine. Maybe I should create the machine again but I think that if we solve it without recreating the machine from 0 this issue post could help others that can't.

Comment: try running /usr/share/logstash/bin/system-install